# Ionic 2 - Imagens tabIcon personalizado não aparecem no aparelho

Tags: javascript, css, html5, ionic, ionic2

estou tentando colocar uns ícones personalizados (em svg ou png) na tab do meu app, no ionic serve funciona tranquilamente, porem ao rodar no aparelho (android) o ícone não aparece, estou imaginando que possa ser permissão ou caminho dos arquivo (que estão no assets/images/tabIcon/imagem.svg). alguém já passou por isso?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ServicosPage } from '../servicos/servicos';
import { CotacaoPage } from '../cotacao/cotacao';
import { EventosPage } from '../eventos/eventos';
import { DicasPage } from '../dicas/dicas';
import { ConfiguracoesPage } from '../configuracoes/configuracoes';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {
  // this tells the tabs component which Pages
  // should be each tab's root Page
  tab1Root: any = ServicosPage;
  tab2Root: any = CotacaoPage;
  tab3Root: any = ConfiguracoesPage;
  tab4Root: any = DicasPage;
  tab5Root: any = EventosPage;
  

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

```css
// CustomIcons
// --------------------------------------------------
// Icon used in tabs
// http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/ionicons/

.ion-ios-iconservicos,
.ion-md-iconservicos {
  content: url(../../assets/images/tabIcon/iconServicos.svg);
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 6px 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.ion-ios-iconcotacao,
.ion-md-iconcotacao {
  content: url(../../assets/images/tabIcon/iconCotacao.svg);
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 6px 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.ion-ios-icondicas,
.ion-md-icondicas {
  content: url(../../assets/images/tabIcon/iconDicas.svg);
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 6px 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.ion-ios-iconconfig,
.ion-md-iconconfig {
  content: url(../../assets/images/tabIcon/iconConfig.svg);
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 6px 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.ion-ios-iconeventos,
.ion-md-iconeventos {
  content: url(../../assets/images/tabIcon/iconEventos.svg);
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  padding: 6px 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Serviços" tabIcon="iconservicos"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Cotações" tabIcon="iconcotacao"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Configuração" tabIcon="iconconfig"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Dicas" tabIcon="icondicas"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Eventos" tabIcon="iconeventos"></ion-tab>  
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: @LucasCosta acabei de inserir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de pesquisar e colocar a pergunta no grupo de [Ionic do Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1558333777738228/permalink/1823748201196783/?comment_id=1823750207863249&notif_t=group_comment&notif_id=1484592498949844) a solução é colocar o nome da pasta de imagem como img ou seja estava colocando como images e o ionic não estava reconhecendo.